# Is it bad practice to put more than one parameter in query string and then parse it like a normal string

Tags: c#, azure-functions, webapi

I have three `paramters` that can be `optional`. I couldn't find a better way so I am thinking if I declare my `route` like this below then I can just parse the `query string` of `anythingElse` and say for example if it has this `parameter` in it then take it, if you find this string literal as parameter then take it etc.... so basically treating `anythingElse` as a normal string and just parsing it to see if I find the `optional` parameters I am looking for.

```
[FunctionName("MakeMeRich")]
public async Task<IActionResult> MakeMeRich(
[HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = "createmoney/printdate/{printDate}/{anythingElse?}")] HttpRequest req,
    ILogger log, string printDate,string? anythingElse)
```

I wanted to see if that is a **wrong** way of doing things and if it is then **what do you suggest?**

Comment: Why not just use normal query parameters `createmoney/printdate?printDate=...&anythingElse=...` and leaving out any parameters that are optional when calling

Comment: @Charlieface would you mind writing the declaration syntax for the route so it would give me what you have in the URL . Thanks.

Comment: Just do `Route = "createmoney/printdate"`

Answer (score 0):

I personally wouldn't do it this way,
Instead I would make the function accepts body that I read and get data from.

I would change this to a POST, as the name hints (CreateMoney), this is a verb/action, isn't getting an entity, so this is more suited to a POST than a GET

Comment: It is not uncommon to send body with GET request. A side question, what is the function doing when called?

Comment: Sending a body in a `GET` is not to HTTP spec, even though people do it

Comment: @MidTown The fact that you don't know what would be passed is a hint that your entity isn't defined. You need to set expectation of what would come in the route, a random value coming for any purpose like that hints to bad design underneath. Also the route hints to it being a POST (CreateMoney). This really should be a POST and have the data in body

Comment: @Mocas I know it should really be a POST but unfortunately I am dealing with some people that want it as a GET !